# EF Core change tracker doesn't increment ID on DbSet.Add()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to save an entity with field `images`, an array of this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

By using this:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static EntityEntry<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return exists ? null : dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is the function that adds the images to the db:

```
private async Task AddImages(TVgnItmEst entity)
{
    if (entity.VgnItm.Images != null && entity.VgnItm.Images.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var image in entity.VgnItm.Images.ToList())
        {
            var resultingImage = images.AddIfNotExists(image, theImage => theImage.Url == image.Url);

            if (resultingImage != null)
            {

                VgnItmImage newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.VgnItm.Id, ImageId = resultingImage.Entity.Id };

                vgnItmImages.AddIfNotExists(newVgnItmImage,
                    x => x.VgnItmId == entity.VgnItm.Id &&
                        x.ImageId == resultingImage.Entity.Id);
            }
        }
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The entity in the function has 2 images, with Id = 0 (brand new):

[image]

After `AddIfNotExists` runs twice, once for each image, this `dbSet.Add(entity);` adds the second image to the change tracker with an Id of 1 also, so it causes an error:

[image]

Why does the Id of the second entry not auto increment to 2? (The urls are different as shown down the bottom of the question).

This is the Db config for Image:

```
         modelBuilder.Entity<Image>(image =>
        {
            image.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            image.HasKey(img => img.Id);
            image.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            image.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        });
```

I forgot to add this. This is the entity with the Images on it:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItm>(vgnItm =>
    {
        vgnItm.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
        vgnItm.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        vgnItm.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
        vgnItm.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        vgnItm.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        vgnItm.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
        vgnItm.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
        vgnItm.HasMany(q => q.Images)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.Id);
    });

[Serializable]
public class VgnItm : CreatedBySomeone
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}
```

The join table:

```
[Serializable]
public class VgnItmImage : DomainEntity<int>
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(VgnItm)), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int VgnItmId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image)), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public VgnItm VgnItm { get; set; }
}

        modelBuilder.Entity<VgnItmImage>(viImage =>
        {
            viImage.HasIndex(g => new { g.VgnItmId, g.ImageId }).IsUnique();
            viImage.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            viImage.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            viImage.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        });
```

@Progman asked if my db/table is configured for autoincrement. I found this in my database manager (SQLPro) that looks quite relevant, the images table is missing from "Sequences" which seems like it would be a generation sequence:

[image]

@GertArnold has said the urls are the same, however they are not. This is the 2 images I'm trying to add:

[image]
[image]

I don't think it is the db because I have done this now:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Image>(image =>
        {
            image.HasKey(img => img.Id);
            image.Property(e => e.Id).UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();
            image.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            image.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        });
```

Which has got my migration to show this now:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Images",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityAlwaysColumn),
                Url = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
                IsMain = table.Column<bool>(type: "boolean", nullable: false),
                CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
                UpdatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Images", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Images_VgnItms_Id",
                    column: x => x.Id,
                    principalTable: "VgnItms",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

And i ran that migration, and the db manager shows this now, so images table should auto increment:

[image]

However I get the same error still.

Since no one has had a working solution even with quite a lot of attention, I'm wondering if the issue is in some code that I have not posted. So here is the parent function which calls `addImages`. It essentially takes a `VgnItmEst` (entity that has a VgnItm, which has list of `Images`) that is already in the DB, but has some changes such as new images added, and saves all changes to the DB:

```
    public async override Task<TVgnItmEst> Update(
        int vgnItmIdParam, TVgnItmEst entity)
    {
        var toReturnVgnItm = entity.VgnItm;
        entity.VgnItmId = entity.VgnItm.Id;
        var toReturnEst = entity.Est;

        context.Entry<TVgnItm>(entity.VgnItm)
                .State = EntityState.Modified;

        int? estId = null;

        if (entity.Est != null)
        {
            var x = ests.AddIfNotExists(entity.Est,
                x => x.PlaceId == entity.Est.PlaceId);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            estId = ests
            .Single(a => a.PlaceId == entity.Est.PlaceId).Id;
        }

        await AddImages(entity);

        entity.EstId = estId;
        entity.Est = null;
        entity.VgnItm = null;
        entity.Id = 0;

        var y = entities.AddIfNotExists(entity,
                    x => x.VgnItmId == entity.VgnItmId &&
                        x.EstId == estId);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        var entityId = entities.Single(a => a.VgnItmId == entity.VgnItmId && a.EstId == entity.EstId).Id;
        entity.Id = entityId;

        var entity1 = entities.FirstOrDefault(
            a => entityId == a.Id);
        if (entity1 != null)
        {
            entity1.Price = entity.Price;

            if (typeof(TVgnItmEst) == typeof(EventItmEst))
            {
                var newEntity1 = entity1 as EventItmEst;
                var newEntity = entity as EventItmEst;
                newEntity1.Dates = newEntity.Dates;
            }
            try
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (Exists(entity.Id))
                {
                    throw;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (Exists(entity.Id))
            {
                throw;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        entity.VgnItm = toReturnVgnItm;
        entity.Est = toReturnEst;

        var viSearchDto = mapper.Map<VgnItmSearchDto>(entity.VgnItm);
        _searchIndexService.UpdateVgnItmIndex(viSearchDto);
        _searchIndexService.ReIndexVgnItmEsts(context);
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Never fully understood the ValueGeneratedOnAdd, as I don't know if it reaches the db to get a max Id, or checks the max Id from the context (client-side)...but...can you try to call `SaveChangesAsync` after each entity you add and see what happens?

Comment: Or: if you configure relations properly in EF, like: parent.HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOne(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId), you don't need to have a generated id prior, in order to do a `child.ParentId = _generatedId_`, you can just do a `parent.Children.Add(child)` (while the Id's are all default, 0 ), and when you save, entries are inserted with proper key and foreign key automatically. For this you could instead use `UseIdentityColumn` instead of `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`.
I don't know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: @Ergis The first suggestion didn't work. I will look into doing it the ef core automatic way. I have steered clear of that, because it made primary keys that are not just `Id`. So it would have `ImageId` as the primary key for `Image`, which is horrible for inheritance.

Comment: I didn't understand the full logic of your code, but I suggest to check if you can use Guid instead of integers as identifier. In this way you could manage them directly in .NET. You could use `Guid.Empty` for new items and Guid.NewGuid() to assign an id.

Comment: `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` doesn't automagically make your property auto-incremented. You either make it `Identity` or configure a sequence for it.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Is your database/table configured to generate an (auto increment) ID for that column for new rows?

Comment: You add two images with the same url.

Comment: @Progman Check the additional info at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Eldar I see `"Id" integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,` in "script.sql" for my other tables, but my Images table is not even in "script.sql". I see in my migration builder, `Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),` for my other tables but my Images table has only `Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),`. So there is the issue. I just need to figure out how to get those into my Images table.

Comment: You can use `image.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().UseHilo("Image_Id_seq")` and then create a migration. This will create the necessary sequence and will use it on inserts.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the database. It's about EF's change tracker and it happens before EF even tries to run insert statements.

Comment: @Eldar for some reason useHiLo always has compile time errors about ambiguity which I haven't managed to solve yet. Might be an ef core 7, .net 7 thing with postgres.

Comment: @GertArnold I have added the urls to the bottom of the question to show they are different.

Comment: @GertArnold Also I think you are right about it not being the DB, I have explained at the bottom now that I made changes to the db that would fix it if it was the db.

Comment: By now it's become impossible to follow the code. However, the exception says that two instances with the same key value are attached to the context, which of course easily happens by calling this `AddIfNotExists` method all the time, esp. on this `new VgnItmImage`. Why, if the image was added by `AddIfNotExists`, do you add yet another instance of it? It seems to me this code has grown needlessly complex by several iterations of trial and error. Maybe it's time to step back and reconsider what it actually should do. Saving one `TVgnItmEst` object with a couple of images can't be that complex.

Comment: In fact, the current title "EF Core change tracker doesn't increment ID on DbSet.Add()" portrays a misconception. `DbSet.Add()` never increments an ID value. ID values are generated by the database when a record is inserted and only then does EF read it back and assigns it to the entity's ID property. But, as said, the process never makes it to that stage.

Comment: Are you using multiple providers? Or some 3rd party libraries that uses. ( EF core extensions package had similar issue but they solved it)

Comment: you need to configure Entity Framework to treat the VgnItm.Images collection as a complex type instead of a separate entity. You can do this by removing the DbSet<Image> property from your DbContext and removing the HasMany(q => q.Images) configuration from the VgnItm entity configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage code is irrelevant, the problem is the model, and more specifically this fluent configuration:

```cs
vgnItm.HasMany(q => q.Images)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.Id);
```

Here the type of `k` is `Image`, `k.Id` is referring to the `Image` PK (primary key), which is *unique*, so basically the relationship becomes one to one, even if you say `HasMany`.

That's why regardless of how many `Image` instances you add, EF Core will assign the principal PK to them, hence repeating value you see and the exception.

This by the way is also the reason EF Core ignoring `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` on `Image.Id`. Normally you don't need data annotations / fluent configuration for property called `Id` of type `int` - it is automatically considered PK, required and auto-generated.

Now, since what you really are trying to map is neither one-to-one nor one-to-many, but many-to-many with explicit join entity type and skip navigations, replace the above with something like this:

```cs
vgnItm.HasMany(e => e.Images)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity<VgnItmImage>();
```

`UsingEntity` has several overloads, which allows you to configure the join entity itself, but here it is not needed since you already are configuring it via data annotations / fluent calls.

Also, in case you are using pre EF Core 7.0 version, you need to define inverse collection navigation property, e.g.

```cs
public ICollection<VgnItm> VgnItems { get; set; }
```

in `Image`, and specify it in the configuration

```cs
.WithMany(e => e.VgnItems)
```

That was a limitation/requirement for many-to-many relationship with skip navigations which has been removed in EF Core 7.0.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using EF Core 7.0. I don't want the Image to know about VgnItms but it doesn't matter much if it does. But I do get `Npgsql.PostgresException : 23503: insert or update on table "VgnItmImages" violates foreign key constraint "FK_VgnItmImages_Images_ImageId"

DETAIL: Key (ImageId)=(0) is not present in table "Images".` When I run the code in the question that adds images.

Comment: After also deleting `image.HasKey(img => img.Id); image.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); ` from `modelBuilder.Entity<Image>` I can add one image at a time but when I try multiple it throws `DETAIL: Key (ImageId)=(-2147482640) is not present in table "Images"`.

Comment: These are different problems which now could be caused by the usage code. Just to be clear, you generated new migration after modifying the model and applied it to the database?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will award this as the answer. I might have to ask a question for the new issue then. First, any idea what my next issue is? In this line `var resultingImage = images.AddIfNotExists(image, theImage => theImage.Url == image.Url);` resultingImage has an Id of 0, and then it gives the error. Since `resultingImage` is not null, it means it called DbSet.Add with it, and it did not assign it a new id. But it occasionally has a non-zero id and works. There are 10 images in the db with id's between 1 and 57 from the times it worked.

Comment: I'll check the code and let you know. Just wanted to be sure the model and db are in sync. The code itself looks overcomplicated for what it does.  Normally it's enough to resolve the related entity instances and then simply add/update object. Also before `SaveChanges`, auto-generated Ids contain temporary negative values rather than the actual values, and functions like your `AddIfNotExists` which search the database for such values are useless. But all this is in genera, let me see how your concrete code performs and if I can reproduce the new issue(s).

Comment: I'm trying to do it simply now. If I call `var y = entities.Update(entity);` when the entity has a VgnItm which has 3 new images with id 0, should that be enough to make it add the images to the db? As The images don't get added.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple when entity contains collection. First, it depends whether the `VgnItem` exists or not in the db. Second, it depends what the input `VgnItm.Images` is supposed to contain, i.e. whether it is supposed to fully replace the items in the db or not. Also M2M adds additional complexity, since this collection represents both `Image` entities and *links*, hence both must be resolved independently. Also the explicit link entity in your model has its own PK field, which further complicates the update. None of these is handled automatically by EF Core.

Comment: Thanks. If the models look workable to you now, then I will just simplify the usage as much as I can, and ask a question with simpler code if I can’t get it working.

Comment: For now, changing this `newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.VgnItm.Id, ImageId = resultingImage.Entity.Id }` to `newVgnItmImage = new VgnItmImage { VgnItmId = entity.VgnItm.Id, Image = resultingImage.Entity }` inside `AddImages` should be enough. i.e. set the navigation property instead of FK property. Because from some point EFC started not updating the auto-generated PK property in the object, so the FKs set that way will always be 0, which then will result in FK violation error.

Comment: I was just about to let you know that I got it working by doing: `var resultingImage = images.Add(image);await context.SaveChangesAsync();var imgId = images.Single(a => a.Url == image.Url).Id;` to get the correct image id. But your way is much more performant since it isn't doing an extra db save and fetch, and is working too so I have changed it to that, thanks!